# Como mover arquivos com copy do PHP?

Tags: php

Usando o copy do PHP, como posso copiar o arquivo para uma determinada pasta sem precisar indicar o nome do arquivo anterior?

Exemplo:

```
<?php
   // aqui eu indico o diretorio onde esta e o nome do arquivo
   $origem = 'pasta1/s.txt';

   // aqui eu indico a pasta de destino mas eu n quero colocar o nome aqui.
   // so a pasta e fazer a copia do arquivo. 
   $destino = 'teste/s.txt';

   if (copy($origem, $destino))
   {
      echo "Arquivo copiado com Sucesso.";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Erro ao copiar arquivo.";
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mover arquivos é com [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rename.php), e não com `copy`:

```
bool rename ( string $oldname , string $newname [, resource $context ] )
```

Notar que no Windows, o `rename` só move entre **discos diferentes** a partir da versão 5.3.1

Quanto a "não querer" por o nome no destino, me parece um requisito artificial do seu código, mas se é isso que você quer, basta criar uma função para isso (se o código fosse meu, eu simplesmente poria a variável do nome nos dois lugares e resolvido).

### Solução

```
function moveSemPorONome( $origemComNome, $destinoSemNome ) {
   $partes = pathinfo( $origemComNome);
   $destinoComNome = $destinoSemNome . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $partes['basename'];
   return rename( $origemComNome, $destinoComNome );
}
```

Note que não acrescentei proteção para detectar se o caminho destino está com a barra final ou não. Forneça o parâmetro sem a barra (ou acrescente ajuste a função, provavelmente usando `rtrim` para tirar a barra final).

### Se quiser mesmo usar o `copy`

Basta usar exatamente a mesma função, mudando a linha do return para

```
   return copy( $origemComNome, $destinoComNome ) && unlink( $origemComNome );
```

Neste caso, você precisa ajustar a função do jeito que achar adequado para retornar e tratar situações como a cópia ter sido bem sucedida, mas a deleção não.

Comment: obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 2):

A função PHP copy exige o nome do arquivo, tanto na origem quanto destino.

Não sei se o que você quer é fixar o nome do arquivo no código.

```
<?php
$pastaO = "pasta1/"; // pasta de origem
$pastaD = "teste/"; // pasta de destino
$arquivo = "s.txt"; // arquivo

if (copy($pastaO.$arquivo, $pastaD.$arquivo))
{
echo "Arquivo copiado com Sucesso.";
}
else
{
echo "Erro ao copiar arquivo.";
}

?>
```