# Mover vários arquivos .xml para outro diretório PHP

Tags: php

Diretório atual

***Xmls/vários arquivos aqui....***

Quero passar todos arquivos de dentro do Xmls para

***Xmls/XmlsLidos***

Tentei fazer com `copy` e depois usar `unlink`, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Da uma olha http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121314/como-mover-arquivos-com-copy-do-php, talvez ajude.

Comment: Deste jeito que está na resposta desta pergunta, somente passa o arquivo se você indicar o nome e passa somento um arquivo. Meu problema seria com vários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um processo que pode ser feito com a função, [glob](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) e [rename](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rename.php):

```
<?php

    // pega a lista de arquivos com a extensão xml.
    $list = glob(__dir__.'/xml/*.xml');

    // diretorio aonde serão remanejados. 
    $save = __dir__.'/xmllido/';

    foreach ($list as $value) {
        if (rename($value, $save.basename($value))) {
            echo 'item enviado com exito';
        }
    }
```